# How is the "change" column on the reputation leagues calculated?

Tags: support, reputation-leagues

I went to the Stack Exchange reputation leagues and stumbled on the "change" column. I don't understand how it is calculated.

> [image]

- Is it the number of changes that the user has made this year compared to previous year?
- Did user 4’s rank not change last year compared to this year? Or did it not change this year?
- Did user 2’s rank improve by 23383 compared to last year?
- Is the change column calculated in another way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The **Change** is actually the **shift in rank**, or movement of the user up or down the leaderboard from last time. For example, if my rank was 7000 last week, and it's 2000 this week, my change or movement would be +5000.

Overall, the change tends to be disproportionately higher for people in lower ranks. Don't read too much into it.